# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null after calling getElementById()

Tags: javascript, null, getelementbyid

I've just started learning JavaScript (properly :D) and I'm having a hard time dealing with the above mentioned error. The browser that I'm using is the latest `Google Chrome` on a Debian Jessie 64bit system. The code is embedded inside the `<script/>` tag of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
    <head/>

    <body bgcolor="white">
        <p><u>Counter:</u></p>
        <div id="counter"/>
        <p><u>Temperature conversion:</u></p>
        <div id="temperature"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function printRange(_from, _to) {
                // ...
            }

            function fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheits) {
                return 5/9 * (fahrenheits - 32);
            }

            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = printRange(2,-10); // (1)

            var fahrenheits = prompt("Enter Fahreheit degrees", 50);
            var celsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheits);
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            para.textContent = fahrenheits + "F = " + celsius + "oC";
            document.getElementById("temperature").appendChild(para); // (2)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `document.getElementById("counter")` (marked with **1**) is working fine however the mentioned error occurs at `document.getElementById("temperature")` (marked with **2**) even though both `<div/>`s are basically one after the other and both appear before the `<script/>` tag where these are being referenced. I do understand that the error comes from `document.getElementById("temperature")` returning `null` but I haven't got the faintest idea WHY the script is unable to find the given ID through this function call.

Comment: You're trying to use XHTML, but it's very likely that the browser is ignoring that and interpreting it as HTML. Because of that, the self-closing notation is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only a certain subset of elements that you can use without a closing tag. That is the implicit use case of `/>`. The subset is known as ["void elements"](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#void-elements).

As a result of `div` not being one of those elements, your `<div/>` tag is simply rendered as `<div>` without a closing tag. The first `document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = printRange(2,-10); // (1)` summarily wipes out the rest of the page with the results of the call to printRange.

Close your elements properly.

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, wow...I didn't know that. Thank you for the answer. Is there a list of non-closing tags somewhere? This is a sort of error that has nothing to do with my JavaScript code and it's a little bit frustrating. :D

Comment: @rbaleksandar - Well, tags which require closure would be the ones not in the list of void elements, which I include a link to above (see:["void elements"](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#void-elements)). The void elements are `area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta, param, source, track, wbr`.

Comment: @rbaleksandar the moon and stars have to line up just right in order for the browser to treat your document as XHTML. Though I accept that there might be some good use cases for XHTML, I don't think it's for everybody and life is easier generally if you just code for HTML5.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the link. Thanks again! Will mark this as answer in a few minutes when SO allows me to. :D

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. Will consider your advice. I've just started reading "Beginning JavaScript" (4th edition) and it is used there but the author hasn't explained in much detail (for now) why that is used.

Comment: @rbaleksandar also a JavaScript book from 2009 is *ancient*. It might be a good book, but it predates a tremendous amount of development in the JavaScript world. [Kyle Simpson's *You Don't Know JS*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) series is available for free online and you might find it a useful additional reference.

Comment: Yeah, I guess 7 years is quite the time period. Will give Simpson's series a shot for sure (took the "Beginning JavaScript" from a library so it's not a waste :D).

Comment: Small update - there seems to also be a 5th edition (from 2015) of the *Beginning JavaScript*. Will also give that a shot along with Simpson's series.

Answer (score 0):

technically self-closing tags are disallowed in HTML 4.x but are allowed in XHTML -- could you try not self-closing the div tags?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud1cr77a/)

```
<div id="temperature"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll mark @TravisJ's as the correct one since it provides more info but you get a +1 from me for the effort.